# How to read an ASP session in PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, session, admin

I'm developing an additional plugin for a domain manager that was built in ASP. The login was made in ASP and I'm developing the plugin in PHP.

So is there a way to know whether the admin is logged in or not?

PS: There is an ASP cookie. Name: `ASPSESSIONIDQSCATBSQ` Content: `LIDBFKDAEJLNGCOILLIDDAEH`

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

Store your sessions in the SQL database, probably MSSQL. Then it would be possible for PHP to connect to that database and simply read session contents.

I do think this is the way it should be propperly done, but it is not that simple.